# Acknowledge receipt of email or answer it?

Tags: etiquette, email

My professor sent me an email. At the end of the email he asked for receipt acknowledgement.

Please should I send the receipt acknowledgement separately and then answer the email or just answer the email, giving that I will do it instantly?

Comment: If you can answer immediately, do so. Else, acknowledge with a estimated date for an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably best to acknowledge first anyway, since there is inevitably some risk that "instantly" becomes less instant...

Comment: "I have received your email and will respond to it shortly."

Answer (score 1):

If you can reply instantly, that covers the request for an acknowledgement and you don't need to send two separate messages.